# why json.parse inserts a backslash before #

Tags: ruby, json

I have a JSON file as following :

```
[

    {"testid" : 1, "desc" : "with valid email", "rescode" : 200, "request" : {"my_user" : {"email" : "#{$user.email}", "password" : "abcde"}, "source" : "android"}},

    {"testid" : 2, "desc" : "with valid phone", "rescode" : 200, "request" : {"my_user" : {"phone" : "#{$user.phone}", "password" : "abcde"}, "source" : "android"}}
]
```

Now, when I try to parse this JSON to get a Hash using `JSON.parse()`, the content I get has a backslash before the `#` as follows :

```
{"housing_user"=>{"email"=>"\\#{$user.email}", "password"=>"abcde"}, "source"=>"android"}
```

It is preventing me from using the value of `$user.email` and instead `\\#{$user.email}` is being used.

How can I prevent this ?

Comment: The syntax construct `#{}` reserved in Ruby and used for strings interpolation. So, `JSON.parse` just escape `#` symbol to prevent string interpolation.

Comment: `JSON.parse()` doesn't add backslash, Ruby does when you display it with `.inspect` (e.g. in irb) for the reason @bronislav mentioned. In fact it looks like `"\#{$user.email}"`, I can't get double backslash.

Comment: @VictorMoroz, you're right. It's definitely `.inspect`

Comment: @VictorMoroz : Yeah I am getting \#{$user.email}, the double backslash got into the question by mistake.

Comment: So, is a there a way I can get my hasmap after parsing the jason as {"my_user"=>{"email"=>"#{$user.email}", "password"=>"abcde"}, "source"=>"android"}

Comment: That's exactly what you have. Backslash exists only when displaying it with `inspect`. Can you get it without a backslash using `inspect`? No.